# sqlite - can I create a user function based on a core function?

Tags: sqlite, function, datetime

SQLite has a core strftime() function. Instead of writing `strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', x, ...)` every time I want the datetime in ISO format, I'd like to have a function `isotime(x, ...)` which will simply return the value of the parameterized `strftime()`.

Is it possible? I'd rather *not* change sqlite3.c directly and/or copy&paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create new functions:

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html

Keep in mind that using them will bind your SQL statements to your particular modified implementation.

EDIT:

[This tutorial](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html) contains an example of creating and registering a new SQLite function.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear - I *don't* want to copy the C code that is already written. Using create_function() would require writing my own implementation or copying strftime().